# VueJS - how pass input parameters to the single page component

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-props

I use **Laravel**, and I wan't to pass parameters to the single page **VUEJS component** from **blade.php** template.

`<example-component :userName="{{ Auth::user()->name }}"></example-component >`

In my **app.js** file, I have a code:

```
window.axios = require('axios');
window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';

window.Vue = require('vue');

import 'es6-promise/auto';

import store from './store'

Vue.component('example-component', require('./components/ExampleComponent.vue').default);

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#main',
    store
    }
});
```

This is code of my **ExampleComponent.vue**:

```
<template>
<div>
    {{userName}}
</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    props: ['userName'],
    data(){
        return {
            temperature: ''
        }
    },
    computed: {

    },
    methods: {
    }
}
</script>

<style>

</style>
```

I have error
**[Vue warn]: Error compiling template:**
**invalid expression: Unexpected identifier in**

```
user name
```

**Raw expression: :username="user name"**

How to pass parameters to the single page **VUEJS component** from **blade.php** template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this

```
<example-component user-name="{{ Auth::user()->name }}"></example-component>
```

Use [kebab case](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#Prop-Casing-camelCase-vs-kebab-case), because HTML is case insensitive.
[Remove the colon](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#Passing-Static-or-Dynamic-Props) because you aren't doing a JavaScript expression